# Мониторинг HTTP запросов

Tags: http

Какими утилитами можно полностью отслеживать HTTP общение с неким сайтом, включая заголовки, GET и POST запросы - в общем ВСЁ что шлют друг другу браузер и сервер, в т.ч. если я нажимаю на какие-н. кнопки на сайте и т.п.

---

CHROME Developer tools не предлагать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wireshark. В фильтре пишите "http".

Answer (score 1):

Наверное поможет один из [этого списка](https://www.google.com/search?q=http+debuger). Мне в свой время советовали [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)